# C# application with MySQL database and deployment

Tags: c#, mysql, database, database-connection

So far, i have:-

> Developed a project using Windows Forms in VS2010 Ultimate. Language: C#,
>   Developed a schema with few tables in MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE.
>   Successfully have been able to use the schema in the project.
>   Created a Setup file for the project too.

Project description: Just a windows form with a datagrid so it can fetch the data from the DATABASE created in MySQL.

Problems:
If a client, WITHOUT MySQL, VS2010 OR AN INTERNET CONNECTION wants to use this application via installation of the setup file, how can he/she access the database?

When a test was conducted to a client with computer deprived of above features, an error is generated which says something like: [code]Unable to connect to any localhost[/code] specified.

I assume that the program cannot find the DATABASE on the very client machine where it is installed as the DATABASE is created on my development machine.

Is there any way that i can embed my DATABASE to the client machine(please be reminded of above criteria on the client machine) so that he/she can flawlessly use the program without errors related to connection with the DATABASE??

Answer (score 0):

Your asking your client to buy sql really, that's the only way they can connect to your database, perhaps you want to look into using xml rather than sql.

This way the client won't have to do anything, unfortunately sql is the easy way, but only if you have the database and sql to access.

For the client xml is easier for them.

Comment: well having database is exactly what i meant. Lets put it simply here. Isn't there a way to just get the whole database to be saved/moved on a client machine while installing my application?? This way, the client himself/herself will be able to work with the application without having to depend on other computers at any instances  for database.

Comment: If they have sql installed then it would just be connecting to your developer database, which isn't the safest option for you ofcourse. However if they do not have sql, you have a problem.

Comment: The problem @Philip Gullick is that client machine won't be loaded with internet always, which means the client wont be able to update the database as he/she wishes.

Answer (score 0):

use the custom action of the visual studio installer to setup the database on your client machine during installation.
 [Guide For performing custom action during installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
You can have a sql file with all the table creation code and just execute the commands during your setup. I've still not figured out how to fetch information from the client machine during installation. I'm also quite new to this so this is all the help I can provide you atm.